# jquery cannot hide span attribute in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, javascript

What is wrong with this jQuery code and why can it not hide the span attribute?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('span.fieldset-legend').hide();
});
```

Heck, just trying to hide the entire span and it still does not work!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('span').hide();
});
```

If it helps, I am trying to hide a horizontal item in a horizontal group.
[image]

I can confirm that my jQuery is generally working.  For example, the below works fine

```
alert('test');
```

This also works fine

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('p').hide();
});
```

Comment: Accidentally pressed downvote and now I can't change the vote until the question has been edited :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess but

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('span.fieldset-legend').hide();
  console.log('Hidden the spans');
});
```

Try the above code and see if "Hidden the spans" gets output on your javascript console. If it does, then the module you're using (Horizontal Groups? or whatever) is tampering with the spans and perhaps showing them after your code has run and hidden them.

Comment: I think you might be onto something with the Fieldgroups module getting priority and "locking" my other jquery modifcations.  I am still struggling with this and I am afraid I might need to hack the JS file in the module to get what I want it to do, unless you know of a way to override the Fieldgroup's module's JS?

Comment: Now I see that the Fieldgroups module is definitely blocking the modifications I want to make to it.  So, I have just went ahead and modified the Fieldgroups horizontal-tabs.js file.  I hate "hacking" the module's source file, but this is what I need to do to get the job done. :(

Comment: You can create a patch file, it's perfectly acceptable as long as you remember to update the patch/reapply after you update the module. Or you can try modifying the weight of your javascript file so that it runs after the fieldgroups js.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code on my Drupal 7 website and it hides all my spans perfectly (display:none). Did you add the spans using jQuery? For example with wrapInner()? If you did check wheter the code is executed before you hide() it. You can also try trouble shooting your selector with a function that always works: addClass('foo'). If the spans receive the classes you can rule out a wrong jQuery selector...

Comment: The span tags were added by Drupal itself.  jQuery is having no problems hiding id or class attributes.  Problem is that Drupal is not smart enough to give the span tags an id or class attribute.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can give every SPAN-element a unique ID with jQuery and adress them individually with CSS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
    var nth = 0;
    $('body span').each(function(){
        nth = nth + 1;
        $(this).attr('id','span-'+nth);
    });        
});
```

Comment: This line in your code is not working: $(this).attr('id','span-'+nth).  It is not adding the 'id' attribute and setting it.  Any ideas why it is not working?  I can confirm that jQuery is finding all the $('body span').

Comment: Remove the first and last line if you paste this code into jQuery. I've checked again and it works for any element. Simply replace span with p, a, div, ... It numbers all elements.

Comment: I removed the first and last line, as you suggested, but it still is not working.  It recognizes all the 'a' and 'span' tags, but is unable to add the attribute.  My page is not adding the "id" attribute and giving it unique values like span-1, span-2, etc...  Are you directly testing in Drupal 7, or just straight out HTML?

Comment: I have tested this code in the script.js file of a subtheme of Zen in Drupal 7. The code works on blank HTML websites aswell. Could you troubleshoot by adding the line "console.log('-span-'+nth);" right below "nth = 0" and another right below "nth = nth +1". Then open the console (CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome) to see the output. If you are not getting "span-1, span-2, span-3, ..." then your jQuery is not working properly... Let me know.

Comment: The error I get is: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function.  Does this help, and what does it mean?

Comment: Well the $-sign is the callsign of jQuery. The error likely suggests that your jQuery code is not properly executed as such. I have no idea how jQuery operates in Drupal 7. I depend on the contributed Zen theme to do that for me. I just add the code in the script.js of the sub theme and it works. It's a long shot, but try adding "(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {" before the above code and "})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
" behind it.

Comment: instead of `nth` you can simply use the counter provided by `$.each()`: `$('body span').each(function(i){ $(this).attr('id','span-'+i); });`. If you're getting $ errors then you can use `jQuery` instead of `$`, or use one of the no-conflict methods, simplest is to use `jQuery(function($){});` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){});`